# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'chrome-extension' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension that calls a JSON through AJAX. I don't know why CORS is blocking me. I'm always receiving errors like this:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://app.zanelo.io/chrome_extension/par12134/par12341243143' from origin 'chrome-extension://fkghhhffemehchbofpdjhnbfclnonemh' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is my code:
manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Zanelo Extension",
  "author": "Kim Ramirez",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "minimum_chrome_version": "92",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Zanelo Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
      "resources": [ "zanelo_icon.png","cog.png" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
  }]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Zanelo Extension</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src='cog.png' width='30px' id='settingclickable'><br><br>
    <div id='homepagecontent'></div>
    <div id='settingscontent'>
        <input type='text' id='parameter1' placeholder='Parameter 1'><br><br>
        <input type='text' id='parameter2' placeholder='Parameter 2'><br><br>
        <button type='button' id='savebutton'>Save
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="popup.js"></script>
```

popup.js

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://app.zanelo.io/chrome_extension/par12134/par12341243143",
          success: function(data) {
              var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              alert(obj.html);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
});
```

I'm trying to alert to test if AJAX call is working and data is coming through the Chrome extension. I really don't know why CORS is blocking me. Hoping to get help from anyone of you there. Thank you so much!

Comment: Add `"host_permissions": ["https://app.zanelo.io/"]` to manifest.json.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm! My Chrome extension is now working! More power to you. :)